# Scalability of private chain with 0 block time

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, scalability, geth-clique

What could be some issues in scalability if a block time of 0 is set to a private ethereum blockchain? If I set it to zero, blocks will only be added to the blockchain every time there's a single transaction. But what happens when the chain scales and you have say, 100 transactions occurring at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

This is, [based on the miner implementation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/what-is-the-default-ordering-of-transactions-during-mining-in-e-g-geth), driven by the function of a Nonce. Not the transaction nonce, a separate [POW nonce](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27432/what-is-nonce-in-ethereum-how-does-it-prevent-double-spending).